# extract filename from path in csh shell -- from list of files

Tags: linux, shell, csh

How to extract filename from the path; i have a list of files.  I'm using csh shell, and have awk, sed, perl installed.

/dfgfd/dfgdfg/filename

should give me

filename

I tried  basename:

```
    find $PROJDIR -name '*.c' -o -name '*.cc' -o -name '*.h'
 | xargs grep -l pattern | xargs basename
```

and it gave me the following error:

basename: too few arguments
Try `basename --help' for more information.

thx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The standard program `basename` does what you want:

```
$ basename /dfgfd/dfgdfg/filename
filename
```

Comment: my issue is slightly different, and basename won't work. check the edited question.

Comment: `basename` only works on a single filename at a time. Replace the last part by `xargs -n1 basename`.

Comment: Also try `-r`, to avoid running a `basename` with no arguments if there are no matches.

Comment: "basename -a" will handle multiple inputs.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of workaround worked for me.  You said you had perl so this should run.  It replaces all nonspace text up to the last / with nothing (effectively deleting it).

```
find $PROJDIR -name '*.c' -o -name '*.cc' -o -name '*.h'
 | xargs grep -l pattern | perl -pi -e "s/\S+\///g"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a nice solution using AWK:

```
    find  $PROJECT_DIR  -name '*.c' -o -name '*.cc' -o -name '*.h' 
| xargs grep -l PATTERN | awk -F "/" '{print $NF}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find $PROJDIR -name '*.c' -o -name '*.cc' -o -name '*.h' | xargs grep -l pattern 
| xargs -n1 basename
```

try this !!

as basename accepet single path parameter as argument, so we force xargs to split it one by one.